# In code behind how do I make a validator to not validate?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Like I have this validator on a TextBox:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtAdd" ValidationGroup="Update" ErrorMessage="*"
    SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtAdd" runat="server" />
```

I want to turn off this validation check in code behind. How do you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rfvtxtAdd.Enabled = false;
```